# networkx in python for removeing nodes

Tags: python, networkx, python-3.6

with this code:

```
$ out_deg = g.degree()
$ to_remove=[n for n in out_deg if out_deg[n] ==1]     
$ g.remove_nodes_from(to_remove)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py", line 434, in __getitem__
    nbrs = self._succ[n]

KeyError: (0, 0)
```

I am trying this code too:

```
$ g.remove_nodes_from(n for n in g.degree() if g.degree[n] == 1)
```

And I get the same error as above.

now, with this code:

```
$ g.remove_nodes_from(n for n , degree in g.degree() if degree == 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py", line 443, in __iter__
    for n in self._nodes:

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Help Please

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code and error messages. And always put full Traceback.

Comment: thanks, do you have any Idea about fixing error?

Comment: what version of networkx?

Answer (score 2):

## Remove networkx nodes iteratively

You can also try using the `g.remove_node()` function iteratively.

### First set up an example graph:

```
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from([(1,2),(3,1),(5,6)])
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure1]

### Then remove node iteratively on condition

```
[graph.remove_node(k) for k,v in graph.degree().items() if v == 1]
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure2]

Answer (score 1):

I can't check for sure in networkx 1.x, but for 2.0:   `g.degree()` is not a dict.  It's a `DegreeView`, which is a networkx specific data type.

When you do `for n in g.degree()` then `n` becomes tuple pairs where the first entry in the tuple is the node and the second is the degree.  So when it tries to remove the node `n`, you really want it to remove `n[0]` --- it doesn't have node `n`.  In your case it dies on the first one where it tries to remove node `(0,0)` which represents node `0` which has degree `0`.

You're almost on the path with `g.remove_nodes_from(n for n , degree in g.degree() if degree == 1)`, but the problem is that as it loops through this, things get removed from `g`.  Then the next call to `g.degree()` is operating on a different graph and python isn't happy to loop over things that are changing.

So try

```
to_remove=[n for n, degree in out_deg if out_deg[n] ==1]  
g.remove_nodes_from(to_remove)
```